# How to run Visual Studio Code locally with localhost?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, npm, npm-install

I need help running localhost to connect with vs code. I am trying to open a phaser 3 game I built.

I have tried npm install -g

I keep getting permissions denied.

Comment: What else have you tried? What are the errors?

Comment: well do you have admin rights on your machine to install things?

Comment: this is the only way to run a phaser 3 game the other way is live serve but it does not allow me to play it on web

Comment: I have admin rights but it says usr/local/lib/node_modules access denied

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with sudo command(if you are using mac or ubuntu)

```
sudo npm install -g
```

If you are using windows, then open the terminal with admin rights. (Run as administrator)

Comment: it says npm err! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file. Im on a mac.

Comment: Ok then you need to intialize the npm then, using. npm init

Comment: How do I initialize it ?